# How can i make an optional field?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, textfield

I am making a Checkout form but i dont know how can i make it optional? I'm new with react js and i badly need help because i have defense some time next week and this is the only problem that i am encountering with the revisions that they have said.

Anyway here it is.

```
const objChecker = (e, id) => {
        const hasEmpty = Object.values(orderInfo).some(x => x == '' );
        console.log(Object.values(orderInfo), hasEmpty, id)
        if(hasEmpty){
            window.alert('Please input all fields')
            return false
        } else {
            console.log(e, 'e')
            setOrderInfo({ ...orderInfo, payment_id: id })
        }
    }



    <div className='checkout_modal_payment_method_wrap'>
                        {paymentMethods.length > 0 && paymentMethods.map(method => (
                            <label htmlFor={`payment_method_${method.id}`} key={method.id} className='checkout_modal_payment_method_item' 
                            style={{display: method.id === 1 && product.category_id === 2 && 'none'}}>
                                <input type='radio' id={`payment_method_${method.id}`} name='payment_id' value={method.id} onChange={(e) => objChecker(e, method.id)} required checked={payment_id === method.id}/>
                                <div>
                                    {method.payment_name}    
                                </div>
```

The only fields that i want to declare as optional is the ADDRESS LINE 2 and TYPE OF EVENT only. The rest will be required

[This is the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG4Ie.png)

Comment: Please post you code as text instead of images. Also please explain exactly what you are asking (what should be optional).

Comment: okay im sorry. i edited it already. the only fields that i want to declare as optional is the ADDRESS LINE 2 and TYPE OF EVENT only. The rest will be required

Comment: thank you for enlightening me @ggorlen